# Redirecting the output of a script to the remote server via scp or ssh

Tags: shell-script, ssh, remote

I have a script which does ssh to all the servers and shows the output for each execution; can I redirect those outputs to `/var/tmp/filename_output.txt` on `server1`?

The script runs from `server1` to all the server. These are the commands I'd like to execute to run the script and save the output:

```
ssh server1
./script.sh > /var/tmp/filename_output.txt

ssh server2
./script.sh >> server1:/var/tmp/filename_output.txt

ssh server3
./script.sh >> server1:/var/tmp/filename_output.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I have been doing some test if you run the command like this you will get local output

```
ssh yourserver < ./your_script.sh > your_script.stdout
```

**END EDIT**

---

From my point of view you have two options.

**Option 1**

After running script.sh on each server and been written the command output to /var/tmp/filename_output.txt on remote server

```
scp /var/tmp/filename_output.txt myserver:/prefered_location/server_name.log
rm /var/tmp/filename_output.txt
```

**Option 2**

Export a NFS from your server and importing on every server on your network, that way you can have a local FS on each of the other server pointing to the main one and your problems are solved by putting the command output on a file inside the FS pointing to the NFS.

If you need instruction on how to export a NFS and import it on client machines let me know

Comment: There isn't any other way to redirect the output to the remote host.

Comment: Checks my edit . I think that is the answer to your problem